How long does it take to recite entire Quran?
If one were to recite in a quick pace..How long would it take to recite entire Quran?

Short answer
A bit over 42 hours if you recite in moderate pace; 10 hours if you take 1 minute per page.
Long answer
Quran.com measure the average reading time of a user, and use it to compute the average time to recite the whole thing. Their data would also be quite vast, due to the sheer number of users reciting almost everyday.
According to quran.com, if you recited from the first Ayah in Al-Fatihah, and made your way to the final Ayah of An-Nas, it would take you 42 hours, 26 minutes, and 17.5 seconds.
Since this is the average, we can say this is the time it would take to recite the whole Quran with a medium pace. Your question specifies 'quick pace', which is obviously in lesser time. If you can recite a whole page, out of the 604 total pages, of the Mushaf in one minute, it would take you 604 minutes ≈ 10 hours.
It really depends upon what you mean by 'quick pace', as it's not a solid definition of recitation speed, but you can experiment with reciting maybe like 10 pages, recording the time it took you, getting the average time it took you to recite each page, then multiply that value by 604 (number of total pages) to get a rough estimate of how much time it would take you to recite the whole Quran, start to finish. The accuracy increases with the more pages you read.
In math language (MathJax is unsupported here, no one expects a math formula in the islamic stackexchange, but you get the idea):
604 * (Total time to read 'n' pages) / n
Hopefully this answers the question, Jazakallahu Khair.
